# How do I extend the session timeout on a page load?

Tags: php, session, timeout

How would I extend the session time out by 20 minutes every time the header is loaded? For example I want something like this:

`$_SESSION['timeout'] = $_SESSION['timeout'] + 1200;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do that.  It will be done automatically by PHP's session handler.

See:

- [session.gc_maxlifetime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime)
- [session.cookie_lifetime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime)